# Email Provider Restriction - Android Studio App

Tags: php, android, email

I'm pretty new at Android Studio and I have to make a proyect, and one of the requirements is that the registration should contain an email address, my question is, Is it possible to put a restriction in the provider? like only emails ending in @utem.edu.mx can register, so further they can login? Should it be on the PHP conection with the App and Database? or in the Android Studio Activity?

THIS IS MY REGISTER ACTIVITY

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    final EditText etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    final Button btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String name = etName.getText().toString();
            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
            final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>(){

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (success){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegisterRequest registerRequest = new     RegisterRequest(name, username, email, password,responseListener);
            RequestQueue queue =     Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
            queue.add(registerRequest);



        }
    });
```

THIS IS MY REGISTER REQUEST ACTIVITY

```
private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://ubisutem.site88.net/Register.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, String email, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST,REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("name", name);
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("email", email + "");
}


@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams(){

    return params;
}

}
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Always check these things server side.  If you do it client side, a hacked client or web browser can still send bad data to your server, which you'll blindly write to your database.  For example if one of the things the client sent up was price, they could override it to say it was free.  So always check all your inputs on the server.

You can actually choose to check on both the client and the server-  that's a good option to increase the responsiveness of the client app.  But don't ever do it just client side.

Comment: but is there a way for only some ending emails like hotmail.com to be available to register? so if a yahoo.com wants to register he should'nt be able to

Comment: Yes-  check the email when the php app gets it, check what the string ends in, and make sure its one of the ones you're ok with.